# How to load page that has unsecure script directly through code in mechanical turk

Tags: c#, .net, https, mechanicalturk

I am integrating amazon mechanical turk with my application (asp.net).

So I have created an iframe in my amazon turk project.In this iframe I am giving the link to my application.

The problem here is.. the server on which my application is hosted is not secure.i.e it is not https. Amazon turk loads only those pages which are https. I tired different things but still chrome says: This page includes script from unauthenticated sources.Only when I click on load unsafe script, the content appears properly.
The workers on mechanical turk are not always going to go on the top bar of chrome and click on load unsafe script.

Is there any way to do this programtically?

thank you.

Comment: That's a _security warning_.  If there was a way to automate it, it would defeat the purpose of the security.

Comment: I don't think there is a way around this. Is there a specific reason you can't use https on your script server? If it is cost they have [free SSL certificates](http://www.startssl.com/?app=1) these days.